# jquery popup registery window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

hello friends This is my membership page,
I want to open the page in this way
from small to large, will efect

http://b1207.hizliresim.com/z/w/b5mxd.jpg
background  will darken

thank you

Comment: Please read up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend
Lightbox - http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

or
Colorbox - http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: thank you I have a problem..use of lightbox syntax <img rel ="ligtbox" I can not use lightbox because I'm using div.. and How do I open a popup div thanks

Comment: There's a Lightbox forum http://lokeshdhakar.com/forums/ You should probably just look for the answer there. You'll definitely find examples exactly like yours.